# Read Excel File inside Zip in Azure Storage. C#

Tags: c#, excel, azure, zip, azure-storage

I have a zip file in Azure storage and there is an Excel File inside. I want to read the excel file without downloading the file using C#. 
I am using a MemoryStream. the code is:

```
public void ReadZipStream(CloudBlockBlob blockBlob)
{
    using (var msZippedBlob = new MemoryStream())
    {
       blockBlob.DownloadToStream(msZippedBlob);

       using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(msZippedBlob))
       {
           foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in zip.Entries)
           {
               if (entry.FullName.EndsWith(".xlsx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
               {
                  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(entry.Open()))
                  {
                       // sr
                  }
               }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

the ZipArchive works correctly and it shows all the data inside the zip file.
the problem is with the SteamReader. It shows a non-readable text so something like:

> ������

I read that the StreamReader is a Text Reader so it cannot read the Excel.
but what is the alternative for it then?

or in another way, how can I read an Excel File inside a zip file located in Azure? 
Thank you.

Comment: An xlsx file is essentially itself a zip file.

Comment: Why do you expect a `TextReader` or any other reader to open a .xls file? Excel files are compressed archives with some XML content. To open it, use an excel framework like EPPlus

Comment: Isn't `DownloadToStream` downloading the file anyway?

Comment: The excel file contains products has to be entered manually to the db. I am not expecting it to read it but I am asking for the alternative.

Comment: DownloadToStream downloaded the file to memory stream. means it is not locally. it will still virtually.

Comment: Once you read the .xls file from the zip, what is your next step? Do you actually need to extract the data from the spreadsheet or you want to process/send the Excel file as is?

Answer (score 0):

> I read that the StreamReader is a Text Reader so it cannot read the Excel. but what is the alternative for it then?

You could leverage [NPOI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/2.3.0) for read/write xls,xlsx as follows:

```
CloudBlockBlob zipblob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri("https://brucechen.blob.core.windows.net/brucechen/LogTable.zip"));
using (var msZippedBlob = new MemoryStream())
{
    zipblob.DownloadToStream(msZippedBlob);
    using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(msZippedBlob))
    {
        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in zip.Entries)
        {
            if (entry.FullName.EndsWith(".xlsx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                using (var stream = entry.Open())
                {
                    var wk = new XSSFWorkbook(stream); //HSSFWorkbook for xls
                    var sheet = wk.GetSheetAt(0);
                    IRow row = sheet.GetRow(0);
                    for (int i = 0; i <= sheet.LastRowNum; i++)
                    {
                        row = sheet.GetRow(i);
                        if (row != null)
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < row.LastCellNum; j++)
                            {
                                string value = row.GetCell(j).ToString();
                                Console.Write(value.ToString() + " ");
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine("\n");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image]

> or in another way, how can I read an Excel File inside a zip file located in Azure?

AFAIK, there is no better approach for you to achieve it based on your scenario. Additionally, you could also refer to [SpreadsheetLight](http://spreadsheetlight.com/sample-code/) or [Aspose.Cells for .NET](https://github.com/aspose-cells/Aspose.Cells-for-.NET), etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it also did not work. it throughs an exception with the stream it is empty.

Comment: I have updated the code snippet with my sample zip file, you could test it on your side.